# Match substring with regex

Tags: javascript, java, regex, pattern-matching

Is there a way to match the following:

```
var text = 'this is a simple text \d oh yeah';
var find = 'text 4';
```

I now want `find` to be found in `text` because it fills the pattern obviously ("this is a simple text 4 oh yeah")

I don't really care which language (Java or JavaScript preferred) but is this possible?

Comment: *it fills the pattern obviously* No, it doesn't. If `find` is the pattern, then `\d` doesn't match a literal `4`. If `text` is the pattern, it's only partially matched in `find`.

Comment: ...well that is actually the point of this question. "text \d" matches "text 4" but I don't know how to accomplish that in this simple setting

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
var someRegExp = new RegExp('text \d', 'g');
var someString = "text 4";
someRegExp.test(someString);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in java

```
"text \\d+"
```

you can see too [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fM7uA5/109)

```
    String s="your string"; 
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("text \d+"); 
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s); 
    while( m.find() ) { 
    System.out.println( matcher.group(0) );}
```

Comment: That does not do what I intend: https://regex101.com/r/fM7uA5/110, the regex should be "this is a simple text \d oh yeah" and it should find "text 4" the demo does not do that

Comment: and how you intend do that? regex is some expression which you you can find it in longer string not opposite

Comment: besides this answer and demo answers  "I now want find to be found in text "